# How to run a .py file from a .py file in an entirely different project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pycharm

For the life of me i can't figure this one out.

I have 2 applications build in python, so 2 projects in different folders, is there a command to say in the first application like run file2 from documents/project2/test2.py ?

i tried something like os.system('') and exec() but that only seems to work if its in the same folder. How can i give a command a path like documents/project2 and then for example: 
exec(documents/project2 python test2.py) ?

short version:

Is there a command that runs python test2.py while that test2 is in a completely different file/project?

thnx for all feedback!

Comment: It's unclear what you need exactly - if the two projects sit close to each other and will always be in the same relative position to each other, you can do this with an appropriate `import`. But if you need to be able to run a Python script in some location that depends on user input or some other unknown variable when writing the code, or if it's somewhere else entirely, you can just use something like `subprocess.run()`. What exactly are you trying to achieve? It's possible this is the "XY problem".

Comment: okay, sorry if i didnt explain it well enough. I have a virtual assistant python script, so basically i made my own Siri/Alexa that can perform tasks for me through voice commands, so i can say certain sentence and then something activates (sort of if this then that sentence). my 2nd project is a shazam-alike application that recognizes music, so basically i want to say like 'run shazam' and then the siri/alexa executes something like: exec(python shazam.py)  since both applications are in different folders i dont how how to run python shazam.py !

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of approaches to take.

## 1 - Import the .py

If the path to the other Python script can be made relative to your project, you can simply import the .py. This will cause all the code at the 'root' level of the script to be executed and makes functions as well as type and variable definitions available to the script importing it.

Of course, this only works if you control how and where everything is installed. It's the most preferable solution, but only works in limited situations.

```
import ..other_package.myscript
```

## 2 - Evaluate the code

You can load the contents of the Python file like any other text file and execute the contents. This is considered more of a security risk, but given the interpreted nature of Python in normal use not that much worse than an import under normal circumstances.

Here's how:

```
with open('/path/to/myscript.py', 'r') as f:
    exec(f.read())
```

Note that, if you need to pass values to code inside the script, or out of it, you probably want to use files in this case.

I'd consider this the least preferable solution, due to it being a bit inflexible and not very secure, but it's definitely very easy to set up.

## 3 - Call it like any other external program

From a Python script, you can call any other executable, that includes Python itself with another script.

Here's how:

```
from subprocess import run

run('python path/to/myscript.py')
```

This is generally the preferable way to go about it. You can use the command line to interface with the script, and capture the output.

You can also pipe in text with `stdin=` or capture the output from the script with `stdout=`, using `subprocess.Popen` directly.

For example, take this script, called `quote.py`

```
import sys

text = sys.stdin.read()

print(f'In the words of the poet:\n"{text}"')
```

This takes any text from standard in and prints them with some extra text, to standard out like any Python script. You could call it like this:

```
dir | python quote.py
```

To use it from another Python script:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

s_in = b'something to say\nright here\non three lines'
p = Popen(['python', 'quote.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
s_out, _ = p.communicate(s_in)

print('Here is what the script produced:\n\n', s_out.decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
exec(open("FilePath").read())
```

It should work if you got the file path correct.

---

Mac example:

```
exec(open("/Users/saudalfaris/Desktop/Test.py").read())
```

Windows example:

```
exec(open("C:\Projects\Python\Test.py").read())
```

Comment: this does not work on my end, is this basically supposed to be working as exec(open("/filepath python test2.py").read()) ?

Comment: I tried exactly this (i'm on Mac). But i got an error. the error doesn't seem to be exec(open("/Users/saudalfaris/Desktop/Test.py").read()), but it still doesn't open. Any other ideas?

Comment: Where is the .py file you want to run? What is its file path?

Comment: i have it as: exec(open("/Users/maxwalder/Documents/school/Labs/tests/python_itspoma/audio-fingerprint-identifying-python/recognize-from-microphone.py").read())

Comment: I think the problem you are facing is that your Terminal doesn't have access to your Documents folder, go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Files and Folders > Then give Terminal access to your Documents folder. Hope it works.

Comment: Well, I am out of ideas.